# Is there a way to access HttpSession from EJB module?

Tags: java, request, ejb, sessionid, httpsession

I'm currently in a need of getting session ID thus I need to get the HttpSession but I don't have any servlets in my EJB module. So perhaps some DI annotation like in webservices api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EJB technology doesn't rely on HTTP so there is absolutely no reason to have HTTP specific stuff in the EJB API. If you need the session id from an EJB (wondering why), pass it as parameter from the web tier (technically, you could even pass the reference to the `HttpRequest` or the `HttpSession` objects and *read* it from the beans but that would be an horrible, wrong, heretic, etc  design, EJBs shouldn't have adherences to the Servlet API). You should maybe clarify your requirement.

Comment: well lets say javaFX applet is run from web with token value of sessionId and when the applet is used it sends data via rmi to validator EJB module which needs to check this session id.
What i did expect is to lookup it in context or inject it or something similar.

Comment: I'm saved sessionId to temporary database table when running the applet from web-tier and then i just compare it in EJB from db.

Comment: @Pascal I would like to generate a log entry in the EJB module that includes the `userid` that initiated the transaction. I could pass the `userid` as a parameter value from a service bean (that has access to HttpSession) to the EJB module, but the problem is that the number of methods is too large and also there are many layers in the EJB module so I don't want to pollute the application with the `userid` field. If there should not be access to HttpSession in the EJB module, what is the best practice to store the `userid`?