# EJB 3.1 authentication on lock up

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss, ejb

I have a Stateless bean where I want to allow access only to the user called **"TestUser"**

I've setted the annotation like written below:

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles("TestUser")
public class LibraryBean implements LibraryIFace {

    @Override
    public void setName(String name){
        sb.setName( name );
    }

    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return sb.getName();
    }

    @EJB
    private SingIFace sb;
}
```

A servlet do the lock up of the bean and return the name.

I want that the servlet must do the login as **TestUser** after can get the name from the bean.
The real user that call the servlet will not have to see none message box or insert user/password.

That's possible?

**UPDATE**
What i mean is that I need the EJB will check the connections to allow o reject in base of user/psw pair, or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interceptor in order to the work, is much cleaner than checking the roles in the bean call.

Your @interface could be like this:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Secure {
   @NonBinding String[] rolesAllowed() default {};
}
```

Then set up and advice to be called when you annotate a method with @Secure that checks the HttpSession for the needed roles and return the login page if the roles needed are not found.

1.- Register the interceptor

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

<interceptors>
        <class>full_class_name_here</class>
    </interceptors>
```

2.- Implement the interceptor

```
@Secure
@Interceptor
public class SecurityInterceptor implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 66355064016557358L;

@AroundInvoke
public Object checkInvocation(InvocationContext joinPoint) throws Exception {
```

UPDATE: Finally, you should access the HTTP session from your interceptor, which is a bit cumbersome and can be described here:
[Is there a way to access HttpSession from EJB module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660949/is-there-a-way-to-access-httpsession-from-ejb-module)

Comment: Thanks for response, I have 2 question about your code. I must implement it into the project where the bean lives, right? What must do the client to be authenticated?

Comment: 1.- At least, the interceptor should "see" the declaration of the @interface 2.- The Controller handling the log.in process should put the role of the user in the HTTP session so it can be checked in the EJB later on

Comment: There is a way to be sure of who invokes the EJB? I need that only my module must be able to access to my EJB and  reject all other connection.

Comment: The problem here it that you are mixing security concerns. One if the users in the HTTP interface (for which you should use the HTTP session) and users deploying EJB in the container (for which you should use the the container security (with the @RolesAllowed and so on...)

Comment: Ok, so what is the correct way to permit the EJB to check who can access to services? I need a way to block not trusted connections.